# How can a function of a complex variable be expressed as a function of both the complex variable and its conjugate

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, functions, optimization, complex-numbers

While reading about optimization of real-valued functions of complex variables ([CR Calculus](https://arxiv.org/abs/0906.4835)). It says that any function of a complex variable 'z' can be expressed as a function of 'z' and conj(z) i.e., complex conjugate of z -

[image: equation]

For a function like f(z) = |z|^2, it can be expressed as f(z) = z.conj(z). But how can we write all functions as function of both z and conj(z), for example, f(z) = z?

Comment: Sure, just because it is written as $f(z,\bar{z})$ does not mean $\bar{z}$ **must** appear.. Likewise you could have $f(x,y) = x$..

Comment: Oh okay, thanks! So we need not introduce conj(z) forcibly in the equation -- or we can not introduce it even if we wished to for some reason?

Comment: analytic functions are precisely the ones which do not depend on $\bar z$ (rigorously $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar z}=0$) so one cannot introduce any non-trivial dependence on $\bar z$ similalry to how in functions of one variable $x$, one cannot introduce a non-trivial dependence of another variable say $y$

Comment: Okay, thanks @Conrad. Does that mean if we cannot non-trivially introduce conj(z), the function is analytic?

Comment: Also, I wish to express few functions as functions of z and conj(z), like the convolution between two signals. I would start with functions of z, but some rearrangement might introduce conj(z) also, like as in |z|^2 = z.conj(z). How do I get such convenient expressions containing z and conj(z)? Is there some procedure for it, or only intelligent rearrangement?

Comment: "cannot non-trivially introduce conj(z)" is quite vague, so yes intuitively it si true, but mathematically this comes from the partial derivative in $\bar z$ being identically zero; $|z|$ is not a function of $z$ only since the modulus by definition involves the conjugation, so that is again quite misleading and one has to look at specific cases, formulas etc with the above generalities in mind as a guide but not as a rigorous rule

Comment: Clearly $\,x=(z+\bar{z})/2\,$ and $y=(z-\bar{z})/(2i).\,$ Thus, $\,f(x,y)=f((z+\bar{z})/2,(z-\bar{z})/(2i)).$

Comment: Thanks Conrad and Somos!